# How to access hadoop cluster which is Kerberos enabled programmatically?

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I have this piece of code which can fetch a file from a Hadoop filesystem. I setup hadoop on a single node and from my local machine ran this code to see if it would be able to fetch file from HDFS setup on that node. It worked.

```
package com.hdfs.test.hdfs_util;
/*  Copy file from hdfs to local disk without hadoop installation
*  
*  params are something like 
*  hdfs://node01.sindice.net:8020 /user/bob/file.zip file.zip
*
*/

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HDFSdownloader{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.getProperty("java.classpath");
    if (args.length != 3) {

        System.out.println("use: HDFSdownloader hdfs src dst");

        System.exit(1);

    }

    System.out.println(HDFSdownloader.class.getName());
    HDFSdownloader dw = new HDFSdownloader();

    dw.copy2local(args[0], args[1], args[2]);

}

private void copy2local(String hdfs, String src, String dst) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("!! Entering function !!");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());


    conf.set("fs.default.name", hdfs);

    FileSystem.get(conf).copyToLocalFile(new Path(src), new Path(dst));

    System.out.println("!! copytoLocalFile Reached!!");

}

}
```

Now I took the same code, bundled it in a jar and tried to run it on another node(say B). This time the code had to fetch a file from a proper distributed Hadoop cluster. That cluster has Kerberos enabled in it.

The code ran but gave an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2115)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2030)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1999)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1975)
at com.hdfs.test.hdfs_util.HDFSdownloader.copy2local(HDFSdownloader.java:49)
at com.hdfs.test.hdfs_util.HDFSdownloader.main(HDFSdownloader.java:35)
```

Is there a way to **programatically** make this code run. For some reason, I can't install kinit on the source node.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Search for `UserGroupInformation` class (or UGI in short) and method `loginUserFromKeytab() `.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I went ahead and used it. I am getting an error:  javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14) - BAD_ENCRYPTION_TYPE. Any idea about this?

Comment: Why don't you google that message? Since you don't care to mention the platform you are running on, the Java version, the type of Kerberos service (e.g. OpenLDAP, Microsoft Active Directory, MIT Kerberos), the Kerberos client config you are using (e.g. `/etc/krb5.conf`) then you are on your own. And believe me, it's complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a code snippet to work in the scenario you have described above i.e. programatically access a kerberos enabled cluster. Important points to note are

- Provide keytab file location in UserGroupInformation
- Provide kerberos realm details in JVM arguments - krb5.conf file
- Define hadoop security authentication mode as kerberos

  ```
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
  import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

  public class KerberosHDFSIO {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      //The following property is enough for a non-kerberized setup
      //      conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "localhost:9000");

      //need following set of properties to access a kerberized cluster
      conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://devha:8020");
      conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

      //The location of krb5.conf file needs to be provided in the VM arguments for the JVM
      //-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/Users/user/Desktop/utils/cluster/dev/krb5.conf

      UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
      UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("user@HADOOP_DEV.ABC.COM",
              "/Users/user/Desktop/utils/cluster/dev/.user.keytab");

      try (FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);) {
          FileStatus[] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/username/dropoff"));
          for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses) {
              System.out.println(fileStatus.getPath().getName());
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks for your answer @saurabh.  Suppose I need to fetch a file from Hadoop cluster every hour. Then I will be scheduling the above code to run every hour. But do I need to execute "kinit -kt principal keytab_path" command repeatedly (programatically or otherwise) for this to work?

Comment: @ak0817 this approach won't require you to run kinit since, you are providing keytab file in the program itself. So it would take care of authenticating itself whenever trying to fetch a file. As for needing to run kinit otherwise, try crontab if you are on a linux system.

Comment: you my friend, win the internet!